# Show layer results in canvas for QGIS 3.0.2?

Tags: qgis, layers, visualisation

For both vector and raster layers, previously in QGIS 2 there was an option asking whether you want layers to be shown in the canvas ("show result in canvas"). Now in QGIS 3.0.2 "Girona" this option is missing and as a result, the layer is not shown in canvas even though it is listed in the panel.

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Why can't I see any layers?

Comment: If you right-click on the layer in the side panel and select "Zoom to Layer", are you able to see it?

Comment: Tried but all in vain

Comment: Maybe your layers fall outside the bounds of the project CRS.